# Route 53 cloudflare traffic-manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cloudflare, amazon-route53

I recently bought a domain name on Amazon AWS route 53 service, i deployed my webapp on nginx and found thousands of unknown access lines on the nginx access.log

> x.x.x.x - - [05/Oct/2020:16:44:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Cloudflare-Traffic-Manager/1.0;
> +https://www.cloudflare.com/traffic-manager/; pool-id: 160ce93223217261)"

they come from multiple ip's and from each ip sometimes we find access every minute or event every second.
is it related to AWS route 53, i didn't configure any health check yet .
thank you for your help.

Comment: Cloudflare is a separate company, that provides separate services, that are not related to AWS. This looks like someone has configured your domain name in Cloudflare.

Comment: I can "imagine" about a possibility. The PublicIP that AWS assigned to you could have been used by someone before. They could have used some cloudflare service and the IP reference they might have had before is probably not removed. I would try to capture the SourceIP (and all Headers) from nginx logs and see who owns that IP (can google for this info. dont know how accurate these would be). If the IPs are owned by Cloudflare, then i would try to open a case with them,"abuse/general", give them the logs to ask/see if they can act/help further. I dont know if they can do anything, but i'll try.

Comment: Thank you for your replies , i ll try to change my elastic ip and see how thing works , otherwise i'll open a case for amazon and see if they can(accept to) diagnose those accesses and try with cloudflare after that, then last solution if none worked , block requests with nginx based on headers (worst case)